# jQuery/JS – Outputting objects inside an array – best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

Need some advice. I am using a jQuery calendar plugin (which seems to be rare!) and it is completely initialised with JS. No HTML.

To add events, you have to write each event as an object inside an array:

```
events: [
        {
            title: "Title of event",
            start: {
                date: YYYYMMDD or "YYYYMMDD",   // "20131230"
                time: "HH.MM"                   // "12.00"
            },
            end: {
                date: YYYYMMDD or "YYYYMMDD",   // "20131230"
                time: "HH.MM"                   // "20.00"
            }
        },
        {
            title: "Title of event",
            start: {
                date: YYYYMMDD or "YYYYMMDD",   // "20131230"
                time: "HH.MM"                   // "12.00"
            },
            end: {
                date: YYYYMMDD or "YYYYMMDD",   // "20131230"
                time: "HH.MM"                   // "20.00"
            }
        }
    ],
```

I am using Django, and would need to write a for loop for each event into this format. So, my question is, what's the best way to do this? JSON? Is this possible? What is best practice to output data as JS objects?

Thanks in advance,

R

Comment: Not sure about django, but in PHP, I would construct a multi dimensinal array and use [json_encode](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert array into javascript parsable object. If there is similar function in django, it will be helpful to you.

Comment: @ahgindia Okay great. Thank you. Is it wise then to output PHP/server-side code into a .js/<script></script> tag?

Comment: you must be having all your events into database, so it is fine to get all your database records in your server-side script and create js object directly on server side.

Comment: @ahgindia Could you show me an example, quickly? Doesn't have to work, but just so I have an idea. I have struggled with this for a while.

Comment: please check my answer for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As required by @rdck, below is an example how it can be achieved :

Server side (PHP example) :

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array(
    'title'=>'Title of event',
    'start' => array(
        'date'=>'YYYYMMDD',
        'time'=>'HH.MM'
        ),
    'end'   => array(
        'date'=>'YYYYMMDD',
        'time'=>'HH.MM'
        ),
);

$arr[] = array(
    'title'=>'Title of event2',
    'start' => array(
        'date'=>'YYYYMMDD',
        'time'=>'HH.MM'
        ),
    'end'   => array(
        'date'=>'YYYYMMDD',
        'time'=>'HH.MM'
        ),
);
?>
```

In HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var events = '<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>';
</script>
```

`events` is your json object which you can pass directly into your events calendar

Comment: Thank you! So, if I was to include this in a JS script function, would this be the best way to do it? http://snippi.com/s/8z9wq4t

Answer (score 0):

I think, best way to do this - is AJAX-request.

But you can add json-string to context-dict and render it in template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var events = {{ json_data }};</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! So, if I was to include this in a JS script function, would this be the best way to do it? http://snippi.com/s/8z9wq4t

Comment: I think this way is better: http://snippi.com/s/elszzeo To render JSON in Django you can manually process your queryset and make json.dumps or use Django REST Framework to serialize and deserialize your queryset.

Comment: Can you explain further? I feel this would be really beneficial in learning. So in the `/api/calendar/events/` file, I would put the array of JSON data?

Comment: Yes, in `/api/calendar/events/` you put JSON. You had not met with AJAX or AJAJ?

Comment: Yes, but just wanted to make sure. So in `/api/calendar/events/` I would have an index.html file where I would output my JSON for events, then simply do what you did here: http://snippi.com/s/elszzeo

Comment: Yes, but it's better to use mimetype `application/json` for JSON, and your `index.html` file should not contain any html tags. But, it's better to use server-side scripts (php, python, perl) to generate JSON-response.

Comment: Are you able to help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564086/requesting-json-file-using-jquery-on-a-django-python-environment?noredirect=1#comment38047902_24564086